# How to output Azure Virtual Network Subnets to csv using powershell for single or multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, powershell, export-to-csv, azure-virtual-network

I am new to powershell and trying to output subnet information for Azure Virtual Networks in either single or multiple subscriptions.

I can output to the console and get the results I'm looking for but struggling to get the same output to a csv file.

I understand that I need to create New Objects, etc. but can't get the correct syntax to work.

Could anyone help please.

Working code below....

```
$subs = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
foreach ($Sub in $Subs) { 
    $SelectSub = Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name 
    $VNETs = Get-AzVirtualNetwork 
    foreach ($VNET in $VNETs) { 
        $Sub.Name 
        $VNET.Name 
        ($VNET).AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes 
        ($VNET).Subnets.Name
    Write-Host " "
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this will do the trick:

```
$subs = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
foreach ($Sub in $Subs) { 
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name | Out-Null
    $networks = Get-AzVirtualNetwork | ForEach-Object {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            name         = $_.name
            subnets      = $_.subnets.name -join ';'
            addressSpace = $_.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes -join ';'
        }
    }
    $networks | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation file.csv
}
```

edit: previous version didnt really work, export-csv is a bit weird, i guess.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Unfortunately this has not worked. It only created a couple of lines, one for each Virtual Network. However, one of the Virtual Networks contains at least 20 subnets and all that was produced from the code above was "System.Object[]".

Comment: what do you mean, only one for each network? how many do you expect in the csv? there was a typo in the subnets, fixed that one

Comment: Some of the Virtual Networks I'm reporting on contain multiple subnets so I'm looking to list all of them. Now that you have made a change to the code, it is now listing all the subnets against each Virtual Network. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

My Variation

```
$subs = (Get-AzSubscription | Sort-Object Name)
$subs | select Name,SubscriptionId
$networks = @()
foreach ($Sub in $Subs) { 
    Write-Output "Processing sub: $($Sub.Name)"
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name | Out-Null
    $AzNetworks = Get-AzVirtualNetwork 
    ForEach ($AzNet in $AzNetworks) {
        ForEach ($Subnet in $AzNet.Subnets) {
            $networks += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                SubsName      = $Sub.Name
                SubsId        = $Sub.SubscriptionId
                VNetName      = $AzNet.name
                VNetSpace     = $AzNet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes -join ';'
                SubnetName    = $Subnet.name
                SubnetAddress = $Subnet.AddressPrefix -join ';'
            }
        }
    }
}
$networks |
    Sort-Object SubsName,VNetName,SubnetName |
        Select SubsName,SubsId,VNetName,VNetSpace,SubnetName,SubnetAddress |
            Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation AzureNetworks.csv
```

Comment: How does your solution differs from the other answer. For me the used commands looks really similar, just more verbose.